# MediaStore Intent doesn't return anything

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera-intent

I'm developing an android app for data collection. This app should have the possibility to take photos, videos, audio-content by using the usual intent-mechanisms.

To start the image-capture intent is no problem. It is shown, and I can take a photo, which is saved on the sdcard. But in `onActivityResult()` the expected values aren't returned, if "Video" or "Photo" are choosed. `resultCode` is != `RESULT_OK`, and `data.getData()` returns `null`. Getting "Audio" seems to be no problem...

There are many tutorials and howtos on the web, but I didn't find that difference, which may result in the behavior of my app...

What is wrong?

For debugging, I'm using a Motorola Defy with Android 2.2, which is connected via USB. The USB-mode is set no "none", so my computer doesn't lock the sd-card.

**Edit 1:**

As a first try, I added these lines into `AndroidManifest.xml`, but there's no difference:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
```

**Edit 2:**

Adding `super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);` to `onActivityResult()`in the activity made no difference

**Edit 3:**

Tried to change the line

```
toDo.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
```

to

```
toDo.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(new File("/sdcard/image.jpg")));
```

but this doesn't work either. The image is saved at the given uri-position, but the app crashes, when it returns to my activity.

Here's the stack (translated from german locale to english):

```
Thread [<1> main] (Paused (Exception RuntimeException)) 
    ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread$ActivityRecord, List) Line: 3605   
    ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread$ResultData) Line: 3647   
    ActivityThread.access$3000(ActivityThread, ActivityThread$ResultData) Line: 129 
    ActivityThread$ResultData(ActivityThread$H).handleMessage(Message) Line: 2147   
    ActivityThread$H(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) Line: 99 
    Looper.loop() Line: 143 
    ActivityThread.main(String[]) Line: 4717    
    Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) Line: not available [native method]  
    Method.invoke(Object, Object...) Line: 521  
    ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() Line: 860  
    ZygoteInit.main(String[]) Line: 618 
    NativeStart.main(String[]) Line: not available [native method]
```

**Edit 4:**

Reverted Edit 3.

Had a look on the return-values of `onActivityResult` again. In the case of video or image/photo this is both right: `requestCode==0x100` or `resultCode==0x101`, but `resultCode==0` and `data==null`.

**Code:**

This is my code:

```
package test.mediastore;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class StartActivity extends Activity {

    private Button ImageCaptureButton = null;
    private Button VideoCaptureButton = null;
    private Button AudioCaptureButton = null;
    private TextView InfoTextView = null;

    final static int IMAGE_CAPTURE = 0x100;
    final static int VIDEO_CAPTURE = 0x101;
    final static int AUDIO_CAPTURE = 0x102;


        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ImageCaptureButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ImageCaptureButton);
        ImageCaptureButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent toDo = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                toDo.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI); 
                startActivityForResult(toDo, IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            }
        });
        VideoCaptureButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.VideoCaptureButton);
        VideoCaptureButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent toDo = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
                toDo.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI); 
                startActivityForResult(toDo, VIDEO_CAPTURE);
            }
        });
        AudioCaptureButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.AudioCaptureButton);
        AudioCaptureButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent toDo = new Intent(MediaStore.Audio.Media.RECORD_SOUND_ACTION);
                toDo.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI); 
                startActivityForResult(toDo, AUDIO_CAPTURE);
            }
        });

        InfoTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.InfoTextView);    
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); // Edit 2 - made no difference
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            switch (requestCode) {
            case IMAGE_CAPTURE:
                InfoTextView.setText("Image");
                break;
            case VIDEO_CAPTURE:
                InfoTextView.setText("Video");
                break;
            case AUDIO_CAPTURE:
                InfoTextView.setText("Audio");
                break;
            default:
                InfoTextView.setText("None");
            }
        } else {
            InfoTextView.setText("resultCode != RESULT_OK");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From your edit3, you need to do this line;

```
toDo.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(new File("/sdcard/image.jpg")));
```

But you actually need to save that File object into a instance variable, then on activity result, if the result is ok, then you just use the File output to access the image/video and so on. If you want, you can insert this into the mediaStore manually on activity result (easily found by googling)

Comment: But I don't want to give a fixed file-name to the new Photo. What do I want: start Camera-Intent, take a Photo, Save it to default location on the sdcard (path/filename is given by camera-intent, f.e. _/sdcard/dcim/Camera/2012-01-10_14-12-10_123.jpg_), back in my app `onActivityResult` gets the uri in `Intent data`.

Comment: Unfortunately thats not how it world on android.. Good design for android is such that any pictures taken from an app needs to be saved on the apps folder on sdcard.. Only the pictures taken from the native camera app should be saved in the default folder.. That being said, it shouldn't be hard for you to imitate the file name and the location of the file